# Docker Compose Client/Server in Bridge

Tags: docker, server, docker-compose

I am trying to (in between other services of the compose) connect this 2 by TCP:

```
autoserver:
  image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:autoserversynchub
  container_name: autoserver
  expose:
    - 5020
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
    - monitor-net

  clientperf:
    image: 19mikel95/pymodmikel:reloadcomp
    container_name: clientperf
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    depends_on:
      - autoserver
```

Where  monitor-net is bridge:

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge
```

So in a python file executed by the client I use a pymodbus library to run this:

```
host = 'localhost'
client = ModbusTcpClient(host, port=5020)
```

Where I obviously have problems with that ´localhost´. When I run each container manually I used `docker run --network host` but now that I am forced to use network bridge I dont know what to put instead of localhost. I have tried with "autoserver", "172.18.0.5" which is the IP given to autoserver by the docker network:

```
"57c6e2c366e81f59636a21b61e7935f68e6c700787b57eba572543e76f35f1ce": {
                "Name": "autoserver",
                "EndpointID": "56e586b875e6d2c17779e236b2448825910d330cc502dec96e2c3ec3771e5bf3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
```

And other combinations, but I dont know how to actually manage to make that connection.

If I try  with 'autoserver' as suggested, it just cant connect:

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line
> 107, in execute
> raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.**str**())) pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus
> Error: [Connection] Failed to
> connect[ModbusTcpClient(autoserver:5020)] [ERROR/MainProcess] failed
> to run test successfully

Comment: You can use the other container's service name `autoserver` as a host name.  You do not particularly need `expose:` or `container_name:`, and if you don't specify `networks:` then Compose will provide a `default` network for you.  All of this is discussed in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried the service name autoserver as explained above and it didnt work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What specific error do you get?